# What are some effective ways a foreign speaker can improve pronunciation in English?

Tags: pronunciation, speech, accent

How can a foreign speaker (where a 
"foreign speaker" speaks English as a second language) effectively improve their spoken English by improving their pronunciation and reducing their foreign accent.

To be more specific, let's assume that the foreign speaker wishes to target a particular regional accent in English.  Let's take mid-western United States as an example.

Note: this is a [cross-post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2085/what-are-some-effective-ways-a-foreign-speaker-can-improve-pronunciation-in-span) from the Stack Exchange site "Spanish Language and Usage".  I posted in both places because I expect the methods for improving pronunciation may differ.

Comment: Visit the country ;p

Comment: Get an American girlfriend.

Comment: Speak over and over with speakers of that accent. By the way, most native speakers in the US wouldn't be able to tell that there is a mid-western accent that is different from the majority of the US population. That is, as far as accents (and culture) goes, there's hardly anything special. Pretty mainstream.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fun and enjoyable ways to practice pronunciation?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8619/fun-and-enjoyable-ways-to-practice-pronunciation)

Comment: [The neutral Mid-Western accent is still what counts as "normal" in the US dominated entertainment industry. A British accent provides a "splash of otherness", when set alongside it](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-17554816).

Comment: Note, I see question as *off-topic* (rather than *not constructive*), per faq proviso "don’t ask ... How to improve my English"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some encouraging [research](https://calico.org/memberBrowse.php?action=comments&id=886) behind the approach used in the [English Accent Coach](http://www.englishaccentcoach.com/) website. It's free and easy to use. You don't even need to login. (I was not involved with and have no commercial interest in the site.)