# English pronunciation by Spanish speakers

Tags: pronunciation

A typical pronunciation problem for Spanish speakers is that of words that begin with 'S + consonant'. For example, `Spain` may be pronounced `eh-spain`. What are other standard (eh-standar) pronunciation issues for Spanish speakers?

(Note: This is a query for specific examples; thus, we do not have here an exact duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62743/50723), which was a little more vague.)

Comment: Interesting but not sure if on-topic here. Is it a possible candidate for a "faq" type question in meta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever English phonology has that Spanish doesn't.

- Distinction between tense and lax vowels.  For example, Spanish speakers may pronounce “bit” like “beet” and “full” like “fool”.
- Additional consonant phonemes:

  - /v/ (confused with /b/)
  - /z/ (confused with /s/)
  - /ʃ/, /ʒ/, and /dʒ/ (confused with /tʃ/).
  - /θ/ (confused with /s/ in some Spanish dialects)
  - /ð/
- Initial consonant clusters /sk/, /sp/, /st/.  Spanish speakers tend to add an epenthetic /e/, as you have mentioned.
- More complex consonant clusters, like /str/ and /ŋkθs/ in “strengths”.
- English is stressed-timed rather than syllable-timed like Spanish.

Comment: Exactly he kind of answer I was hoping for. Thanks!