# The X in Xavier

Tags: pronunciation, history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, french, spanish

The NOAD lists the pronunciation of Xavier as `(ig)ˈzāvēər`. In my own experience the parenthetical pronunciation is very common. I, however, do not know of any other x-initial words that are vowel-initiated when spoken.

**Why is Xavier often pronounced** `(ig)ˈzāvēər`**?**

I have two guesses, but they are merely guesses.

1. While Xavier is pronounced `xaˈβjer` in its native Spanish, it is pronounced `ɡzavje` in French ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xavier_(given_name))). Does English pronunciation follow French pronunciation, but with the initial `g` growing into a vowel?
2. According to Wikipedia the name Xavier comes from the Basque "etxe berri", for 'new house'. Did English somehow maintain the vowel from *etxe*?

What is the real reason Xavier is sometimes pronounced vowel-initial? Has this alternate pronunciation always existed? Are any other English x-initial words spoken with an initial vowel?

Comment: The only "English word" I can think of that starts with an X spoken as a vowel sound is ***xray*** (I don't recognise any initial vowel in Xavier, which starts with a /z/, same as most such words, or with an aspirated /h/). Is this anything to do with [English pronunciation by Spanish speakers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126147/) (apparently they add a vowel sound before lots of words starting with S).

Comment: FWIW, the St Xavier high school in Louisville KY was universally pronounced "ex-avier" when I was a kid.

Comment: Because of X-men. (Actually, I just think it started out as a common error based on the more usual sound of "x," like pronouncing "yttrium" as "yittrium" instead of "ittrium.")

Comment: In teaching me the sounds of the letters, my first-grade teacher insisted that initial *x* was pronounced as *z* because pronouncing it like the *x* in *fox* |ks| would be impossible in initial position. I doubted that and took it as a challenge immediately, and was vindicated years later when I undertook the study of Greek. I now routinely pronounce words like *xylophone* and *xenophobic* and names like *Xenophon* with initial |ks| just to be contrary. But in American Catholic contexts I routinely hear the name Xavier pronounced with initial |εks|.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19493/why-is-x-used-when-we-pronounce-it-z

Comment: The letter *x* is *sh* /ʃ/ in Basque spelling, so Basque *etxe berri* would be pronounced /etʃe beri/. So it seems unlikely that English got the initial vowel from the Basque, especially since the town he was named after already has the initial vowel dropped in Basque: it's spelled *Xabier*. I'd go for the French theory.

Comment: For the record, the phenomenon you've observed with Xavier and its initial vowel is "epenthesis", and the vowel is known as an "epenthetic vowel". It's one of two responses to difficult-to-pronounce consonant clusters, the other being elision, the dropping of one or more sounds. I'm not sure why Xavier gets epenthesized while almost every other initial X gets elided, but maybe these terms can help your search

Answer (score 1):

As an expansion of [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19493/why-is-x-used-when-we-pronounce-it-z), [this explanation](https://www.quora.com/English-language/Is-the-letter-X-in-the-beginning-of-a-word-always-pronounced-as-Z) from Quora rings true:

> Not all, but most of the English words where *X* occurs as the first
>   letter are of Greek origin.
>
> Words of Greek origin that begin with 'X' in English are pronounced
>   with a 'Zzzz' sound because the original sound, sort-of like 'Ks-' or
>   'Ksee-' or 'Kzee-',  has not been adopted in English; at least, not in
>   the front of a word.
>
> For example: *Xylophone*: The word in Greek is ξυλόφωνο, pronounced in
>   Greek a bit like KSEE-loh-fon-o. Similarly: *Xeno*-

There are [a slew of x-initial words](https://books.google.com/books?id=bfLXAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA552&lpg=PA552&dq=why%20is%20x%20pronounced%20as%20z&source=bl&ots=nJwtjr70-5&sig=QCa6JQEsv2LQAo3_wMx-6IlYvvM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAiPKl5-DJAhXIqoMKHZkJA804ChDoAQgrMAM#v=onepage&q=why%20is%20x%20pronounced%20as%20z&f=false) in the English language with this pronunciation.

Comment: It seems all of the _/eks/_amples are very recent and treat X as an initial. It strikes me, then, that Xavier has a different story